sqlcmd is truncating long values or skip headers
I'm trying execute a sql query stored in a .sql file and save the results to csv.
sqlcmd -S the_server -d the_db -U the_user -s ";" -i C:\GIS\Kod\SQL\sqlcmd\test.sql -o C:\GIS\Kod\SQL\sqlcmd\test2.csv

In my query a column of geometries are converted to WKT string which can be up to 300 000 characters, and they are truncated in the csv output.
So I add the -y 0 flag, but then I get no column headers in the csv file.
sqlcmd -S the_server -d the_db -U the_user -s ";" -y 0 -i C:\GIS\Kod\SQL\sqlcmd\test.sql -o C:\GIS\Kod\SQL\sqlcmd\test3.csv

How can I return very long strings and also get the column headers?
